# How to replicate CSS's `border-image` effect in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am looking for a way to replicate the effect that can be obtained with `border-image` in CSS, but within InDesign.

What I'm interested in is having this image smartly resized to fit the block's content (meaning stretching the sizes, but keeping the aspect ratio of the corners intact).

I am looking for a way to do it with an image, or maybe a vector format.